# Sails with Model with array of binary data

Tags: arrays, model, sails.js

I want to know the best way to have an array of images. My thoughts are to have an array like

```
  avatars: {
        type: 'array',
        required: 'true'
    }
```

But, then I don't know if you can have a binary data inside an array and if you can, that would be too much load in your json response. Or, have two **Inventory and InventoryImage** table that stores the images and **Inventory** references **InventoryImages** as a **Collection** and the other as a **Model**. Which is better? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why you store image as binary? Why not upload it to server, and save it's file location path?

Comment: It didn't occur to me. Know anywhere I can learn how to that?

Comment: Try this http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/file-uploads

Comment: Sails only added Skipper to use **AWS** and **Mongo-GridFS** what if my server is on Digital Ocean. How can I do that?

Comment: sailsjs offers to store binary files, and for small files that use case is perfectly vaild, but i dont find a place where it is actually described how to use waterline with binary files